# How to use elasticsearch.net bulk API to import json file by btye array to elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, curl, nest, elasticsearch.net

I have some json file need to import to elasticsearch.
I use the curl api. The below is sample and it work fine for me.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index_local/_doc/_bulk -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @sample.json
```

I use the **HttpWebRequest** to simulate and it work fine for me too.

```
public void Post(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        // get the byte array 
        var data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

        // create HttpRequest
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:9200/index_local/_doc/_bulk");
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        // set the file byte array to the stream
        using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        // get the response
        using (var response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // read the result
                Console.WriteLine(responseStream.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

**But I can't find the bulk api with import json file with elasticsearch.net.** 
Is there have some function equal to **HttpWebRequest** that can post the json file to elasticsearch ? 
 
Is elasticsearch.net library ElasticLowLevelClient or ElasticClient support to import json file with btye array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `sample.json` is a JSON file with a valid structure for the bulk API, you can send the request with

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("sample.json");

var bulkResponse = client.LowLevel.Bulk<BulkResponse>(
    bytes,
    new BulkRequestParameters
    {
        RequestConfiguration = new RequestConfiguration
        {
            RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)
        }
    });

if (!bulkResponse.IsValid)
{
    // handle failure
}
```

This sets a specific request timeout for this request, which you might set to something larger than normal if the bulk is larger than a normal request, which it typically is. If `sample.json` is larger than around 5MB, you might consider reading the file in line pairs (bulk action and document) in batches, and sending as multiple bulk requests.